# How to stop the spree 0.11.0 workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm running an e-commerce using Rails 2.3.8 and spree 0.11.0 (I'm also rebuilding the whole site with the latest rails/spree version but this problem I need to fix right away). I need to redirect the user to a customized view at the moment that the he enters the creditcard information. I have something like this inside my orders_extension.rb:

```
CheckoutsController.class_eval do
 update.after :redirect_to_thank_you
    def redirect_to_thank_you
      redirect_to '/somewhere'
    end
end
```

It actually goes through this action, but I want it to be the LAST action. It keeps doing more requests after my call.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a `completion_route`. You can see it being used [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/controllers/spree/checkout_controller.rb#L39). Right now, it redirects to the Order show page. What I would do:

```
Spree::CheckoutsController.class_eval do
  def completion_route(_custom_params = nil)
    redirect_to main_app.order_processed_path
  end
end
```